# Cant upload SVG files after updating Wordpress 4.7.1

Tags: svg

I updated Wordpress to 4.7.1 and cant upload SVG anymore.

I had a function in my functions.php file

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
   $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
   return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

but it also dont help now.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252143/svg-files-not-uploading-since-most-recent-wp-update

Comment: Read more in the link above. TLDR; Use the following plugin until this issue will be fixed in WP 4.7.2: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-real-mime-check/

Comment: Yep, that's a duplicate too. The first flagged duplicate was the first one asked and has the better answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the thread below, a **temporary solution** would be to add this code to your wp-config file:

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-4-7-1-kills-svg/page/3/

Comment: Thank you very much. It saves me. But this will not make the website unsafe, right? @Don-Silvermann

Comment: Isnt this super insecure?

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only one who has the ability to upload  files to WordPress, no.

But if you allow users to register and comment on your blog, yes..

It is a temporary fix to allow you to upload files. Feel free to remove the code after you upload the SVG files.